# Android Studio WebView - Downloading files with admin-ajax.php extension

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio

I've been learning Android Studio (I'm not an expert). However, I managed to code my WebView app from a website and I can't make it download the files as their original file names... For some reason I'm getting an "admin-ajax.php" file in return.

This is the code on MainActivity.java:

```
  mywebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long l) {
            //file name
            String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,getFileType(url));
            sFileName = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            sURL = url;
            sUserAgent = userAgent;

            //check android version
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    ==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    downloadFile(fileName,url,userAgent);
                }else {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}
                    ,  1001);
                    }
                }else{
                    downloadFile(fileName,url,userAgent);

                }
            
            }

        public void onPageStarted(WebView view,String url, Bitmap favicon){
            onPageStarted (view,url, favicon);
        }

        });

    }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack())
        webView.goBack();
    else
    super.onBackPressed();
}

public String getFileType(String url){
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(Uri.parse(url)));
}

    private void downloadFile(String fileName, String url, String userAgent){
        try {
            DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request (Uri.parse(url));
            String cookie  = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.setTitle(fileName)
                    .setDescription("is being downloaded")
                    .addRequestHeader("cookie",cookie)
                    .addRequestHeader("User - Agent", userAgent)
                    .setMimeType(getFileType(url))
                    .setAllowedOverMetered(true)
                    .setAllowedOverRoaming(true)
                    .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE
                    |DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
            sURL = "";
            sUserAgent = "";
            sFileName = "";
            Toast.makeText( this, "Download Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }catch (Exception ignored){
            Toast.makeText( this, "error"+ignored, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }


public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String [] permissions, int[] grantResults){
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);
    if (requestCode==1001){
        if (grantResults.length>0&&grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if (!sURL.equals("")&&!sFileName.equals("")&&!sUserAgent.equals("")){
                downloadFile(sFileName,sURL,sUserAgent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What could be the issue?

Thank you everyone for the support.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Use this code below. Replace `i.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");`into another type of file extension if :

1. the file extension is not pdf; and
2. you want to open the file after download.

   ```
   public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ...

    private String fileName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition,
                                    String mimeType, long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            //setup the fileName
            //fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,mimeType);
            fileName = (contentDisposition.substring(contentDisposition.lastIndexOf("filename*=UTF-8")+17));

            request.setMimeType(mimeType);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie",cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent",userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Downloading File");
            request.setTitle(fileName));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                    fileName);
            DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            //Registering receiver in Download Manager
            registerReceiver(onCompleted, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));    
            downloadManager.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });

    ...

    BroadcastReceiver onCompleted = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Download Finish", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + fileName);
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(WebViewActivity.this, "com.example.app"+".provider",file);
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you! But it didn't work yet.. I just added another comment with the new code so you can help me please..

Comment: I think it has something to do with a security feature on the website. The code works pretty well but it has its issues with Google Drive files and my web as well :(

Comment: What is the url?

Comment: Sorry Gedanggoreng. The code actually works on other websites... But apparently the problem is with my website, I have no idea why. This is what the wordpress plugin developer told me: "downloads of the plugin are processed via the public admin endpoint of WordPress /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. It seems that the file name set somehow isn't received by the webview framework so that it uses that script name instead?" Does it make any sense for you?

Comment: Can you inform the website url so I can examine it?

Comment: Or can you inform the plugin so I can check?

Comment: Hi Gedanggoreng. Yes of course. This is the plugin: https://codecanyon.net/item/useyourdrive-google-drive-plugin-for-wordpress/6219776

Comment: If you want to try with an URL, you can simply try with any google drive video url. The only issue on the web view is with google drive videos

Comment: Just add the new fileName code. Already tested it. Work with any google drive videos or pdf files. Haven't tried the wp plugin, though.